# Web application, offline mod & synchronisation

Tags: java, mysql, html, hibernate, synchronization

We are a group of 6 students in the last year of our studies.
We have to add new features on an existing web application.  One of the most important feature and in our opinion the hardest one to implement is the following : the web application has to be functional even when offline.
As for, you must be able to consult data, make changes to the data, and when your device will be able to connect again, the app must try and synchronize with the online database.  The current application use the following technologies : apache tomcat / mySQL / Hibernate / JavaEE / JavaScript / Ajax / xHTML & HTML5.

Considering that the main devices that will use the application are mainly digital tablet, smartphones (windows and android, not iOS for now), and windows PC ;  my main question is the following one :

How can you do this kind of thing ?

I've done some research and it seems like you have to do a 'second' application, which will use mainly HTML5 to consult data while offline and JavaScript to control what the user is doing and what he can do. But we have no idea about the synchronization. It seems like SQLite could be of use as well

I know this is a general question but we are in the phase where we try and make sure everyone understands what the next steps will be. Thanks for your help and explanations.

Comment: Well i am also looking for the same, but in my case technologies stack is php mysql.

Comment: There is a service worker in javascript, have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Service-Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) API. Service worker is a programmable network proxy, allowing you to control how network requests from your page are handled. It's the next generation of giving users an offline experience after the [App Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). 
The Service worker - in combination with local storage or even better WebSQL or a polyfill like [localforage](https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/) could be a way to realize that kind of application.

Downside: Service-Worker require SSL, no way around that. Second, only latest chrome and firefox support these technologies.

You might lookup PWA Progressive Web Application as a keyword, which describes / and uses exactly that kind of technologies.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution-1 : custom solution**

There are api available to store data locally called indexDb in javascript which may help to store data.

For synchronisation i found that service workers may help.

**Solution-2 : ready made tool**

You can also try [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) but for this i think at server side you have to take apache couchdb database.  I have not used it but would like to try this once.